# Bind property of collection element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, data-binding

I have a GUI and DataGrid element (C#, WPF). There I have 4 columns - name, value, timestamp and comment. As a data source I use a collection of elements of type Parameter, that has properties name, value, timestamp and comment. How can I create data binding for columns in DataGrid to display the corresponding property of all Parameter elements in collection?

Comment: Are we talking about WinForms or WPF here?

Comment: We are talking about WPF

Comment: Search the internets for "WPF DataGrid tutorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wel, you need to define a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and one time it's defined in XAML, assign to your
`DataGrid` control's `DataContext` the collection of elements you have `List<Parameter>`.

It's not something that can be described in one asnwer, so worth reading of

[WPF DataGrid: Using DataTemplates for auto-generated columns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate)

It's not difficult and pretty intuitive, till you're doing a simple things.